# Should I leave my company when I'm the only developer?

Tags: professionalism, career-development, human-resources, quitting

So, I'm currently a intern at the company I work. I've been here for a year.

However, I feel like the management doesn't give much value the development team. Currently, I'm the only developer that comes here everyday. There is a senior that sometimes comes during the day, but usually comes to work really late (he works on another company during day), so no ones has much contact with him. So, basically I code all the back-end and most of the front-end of the company's products (there is a designer too).

When I got in the company, I was told each 3 or 4 months they would evaluate my development, to tell me how I could improve and possibly give me a raise. That, however, didn't happen. I only got a raise when I asked to, even then, my manager talked to the other managers and they said "We don't know what he does here". They did give a raise, but smaller then what I asked for.

We have a development team (basically, me and the designer) and a BI(Business Inteligence) team. My manager basically works only with the BI team. She is always talking and working with the BI team because that's where she has more technical knowlegde. We talked about this when I asked for the raise. She said since the has so much to do she's usually there. She only really comes to the development team when it's really needed or when I ask her to.

A friend of mine also worked here, but he was already upset with the situation and decided to leave. He has just found a great job at a small company. Depending on how much work needs to be done, he can work at home. He could introduce me to his boss and there is a good chance I would be hired (as a intern as well) and the salary is just a bit smaller than what I get here.

I'm really interested in this offer, specially about the working at home part. I'm almost ending university so that would give me more time to focus on it. However, since I'm the only developer here, I feel like I would cause a great deal of problems since they would not have anyone to develop their products.

This really bugs me because they have hired a lot of interns for BI and other areas but none for development, ever since I started here. I've seen the BI team be completely renewed since I got here. The situation has been like this way for sometime and only recently they started looking for more people for the development team. My manager even said they would depend on me to help these new people.

So, should I go to work with this friend of mine or stay here?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/44576/how-to-quit-when-you-are-the-last-developer-on-the-team?rq=1

Comment: related reading: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/79487/quitting-a-small-start-up-where-you-are-a-primary-developer/79548#79548

Comment: You're an intern. They're not planning for you to be there forever. Don't sweat it.

Comment: *My manager even said they would depend on me to help these new people.* That sounds like a personal problem for your manager.

Comment: Generally, yes. Being the only developer presents a challenge for personal and professional growth. You will be very much isolated from the real world - how to solve real problems the right way and such. Your market value will be going down and eventually you will have to stay in this company forever, because no-one else will compete for you. Worst part is that you will sincerely believe everything is right and being paid 70K after 20 years of experience is normal, while others are paid 200K after 10 years (just an example).

Comment: You're in a similar situation as mine during my own internship, oh so long ago... you are part of a rotating labor force. No one is paying attention enough to even know what you do; when you leave, they'll just find another intern. It's a poor way to develop anything of substance, but it's also a cheap and hands-off way for either a small company like this one or a large company (I was embedded in a BI group at Rockwell-Collins Commercial Aerospace) to let their internal departments get cheap tools built without bothering internal IT.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Whether or not moving jobs is a good move for you, I don't know.

What I ***can*** tell you is that it's not your fault, or problem is your current employer is left in a lurch if you quit.

It is the management's job to make sure that they have a plan in place for that sort of situation (developer quits). Furthermore, you're only an intern there - you are not expected to stick around for a very long time anyway.

What you should be focusing on is finding the opportunity which allows you to gain the most relevant knowledge, and fits best with your school schedule.

Don't let any sort of "guilt" hold you down. Make the move that's best for you.

Comment: However, leave professionally. Give notice, make up a document for where the next person can find things, document any passwords that only you have to production systems, etc.

Comment: Absolutely on both the post and @HLGEM's comment. It's easy and common to feel guilty about this, but the reality is that it's a situation of convenience for them, and their fallback plan isn't your responsibility... that said, even in an actually toxic environment (this seems to be more like mild neglect), go out professionally and remember that the next person will be in the same situation you're in now.

Answer (score 3):

If the company wanted to fire you, it would. No matter what you said, no matter how much you cried.

That said, leave whenever you want. Specially if management doesn't give a crap about what you think, as this seems to be the case.

This is bussiness.

Answer (score 3):

As an employee you have no reason to provide "loyalty" to an employer as employment is at-will.  They could terminate you for just about any reason at any moment, so the thought that leaving them high & dry shouldn't be your concern.

Evaluate the pros & cons of leaving and go from there.  Sometimes the grass is greener, sometimes it isn't.